# Comparable SQL for LINQ query?

Tags: linq

Is there an SQL query that would give me the same result as the following LINQ statement?

```cs
DataTable dtAll1 = userData1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(ra => !userData2.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(rb => rb.Field<string>("A") == ra.Field<string>("B")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    userData1 AS ra
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM userData2 AS rb WHERE ra.B = rb.A)
```

(Updated from `EXISTS` to `NOT EXISTS`.)

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you very much for pointing me in the correct direction. I duplicated the exact data return result by adding 1 modification:

    SELECT        *
    FROM            userData1 AS ra
    WHERE        (NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT        *
    FROM            userData2 AS rb
    WHERE        (ra.B = rb.A)))

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Nevertheless...top shelf answer! Thanks again.